# Rotating a Svg path around center using matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg

I have many svg shape of different sizes, I have to rotate them with different angle dynamically.I want to rotate them centrally using matrix, I am facing a problem in calculating e,f of matrix. How the calculate e,f in matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f). I have an angle, but does not know to calculate new position, so it looks it rotated centrally.Here is an example shape which I have rotated at 45 degree,
[image]

```
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="stroke: #3333cc;fill:none;" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)"></rect>

   <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="fill: #3333cc" transform="matrix(0.707,-0.707,0.707,0.707,100,100)"></rect>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `matrix()` and not `rotate(angle, cx,cy)`?

Comment: The trick is to draw the `<rect>` centered around Origin `(0,0)`, then use `rotate(degree)` and `translate(x,y)`. Works all the time and easier to read vs `matrix(....)`

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I want to learn the mechanism, how the rotation works in matrix

Comment: @AlvinK. I still I need to solve it using matrix

Comment: `rotate(degree offset-x offset-y)` where `offset-x` = width/2 & `offset-y` = height/2. Check the [docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) `matrix(...)` is the equivalent of both `rotate()` and `translate()`. In another words, doesn't matter if you use one or the other, amounts to the same rotation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An intro to how transforms and matrix multiplication works is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.  There are plenty of online resources for that.

And you can read about how SVG transforms work in the SVG specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html

But basically to rotate by angle (a) around a specific point (cx,cy), you have to combine (with matrix multiplication) the three operations:

1. translate the centre back to the origin (-cx, -cy)
2. perform the rotation (a)
3. translate back to the original position

```
[1 0 cx] [cos(a) -sin(a) 0] [1 0 -cx]
[0 1 cy] [sin(a)  cos(a) 0] [0 1 -cy]
[0 0 1 ] [  0       0    1] [0 0  1 ]
```

When you multiply those three matrices together you get a matrix of the form:

```
[cos(a) -sin(a) (-cos(a) * x + sin(a) * y + x)]
[sin(a)  cos(a) (-sin(a) * x - cos(a) * y + y)]
[0         0               1          ]
```

or in SVG form:

```
matrix( ca, sa, -sa, ca, (-ca * x + sa * y + x), (-sa * x - ca * y + y) )
```

Where:

```
ca = cos(angle)
sa = sin(angle)
```

Here is a demo. The green rectangle is using `transform="rotate(a,x,y)"` and the red rectangle is using our calculated equivalent.

```js
var matrix = getMatrixForRotation(45, 250, 250);

document.getElementById("myrect").setAttribute("transform", matrix);



function getMatrixForRotation(a, cx, cy)
{
  var ca = Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 180);
  var sa = Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 180);

  var a = ca.toFixed(4);
  var b = sa.toFixed(4);
  var c = (-sa).toFixed(4);
  var d = ca.toFixed(4);
  var e = (-ca * cx + sa * cy + cx).toFixed(4);
  var f = (-sa * cx - ca * cy + cy).toFixed(4);

  return "matrix(" + [a,b,c,d,e,f].join(' ') + ")";
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  
  <rect x="100" y="150" width="300" height="200" fill="#eee"/>
  
  <rect x="100" y="150" width="300" height="200" fill="none"
        stroke="green" stroke-width="10"
        transform="rotate(45 250 250)"/>
  
  <rect x="100" y="150" width="300" height="200" fill="none"
        stroke="red" stroke-width="4"
        id="myrect"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Why are you using `.toFixed`? That needlessly loses accuracy!

Comment: Two reasons: (1) JS numbers are double precision whereas SVG numbers are single precision. So we can't just output JS values directly as a string. (2) Tidier looking output. Most of the time four decimal digits will be plenty.

Comment: Two counterarguments: (1) Yes you can: see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wizzwizz4/w646ztxk/). (2) Most of the time is not all of the time; why provide code that loses accuracy when you can provide code that doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is plus your X position and negative your Y position.
For example

If you have this code

```
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="stroke: #3333cc;          fill:none;" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)"></rect>

    <rect x="25" y="-25" width="50" height="50" style="fill: #3333cc" transform="matrix(0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,100,100)"></rect>

</svg>
```

The first rect is the normal straight one which is not rotated. To rotate this in the center of the first rect you need to first

```
Divide the width by your x transform (0.5) : 50 / 0.5 = 25
Divide the height by your y transform (0.5) : 50 / 0.5 = 25
```

Then simply use those values in your second rect so the new X position would be 25 and the new Y position would be -25